# Android apk not working properly when installing manually

Tags: android, apk

I am having a problem when i generate an apk file of my project by (Export Signed Application) and then install it in my device (Samsung galaxy Note II) then it is not working properly as it should work. But when i install it directly from ADT by enabling USB debugging and attaching my phone to my computer via data cable. then it is working fine as it should work. what can be the reason behind this. anyone have any idea? please help me.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working properly"?

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: actually in my app. i am using facebook login via latest facebook android sdk. the only problem i am getting is when the user is logged in to facebook the session.isOpened() always returning false, i.e. i am unable to fetch user data and redirect to HomeActivity.

Comment: but when i use USB debugging it is working well. i am getting opened Session and HomeActivity is starting.

Comment: migh be the issue due to hash that you enter on facebook app page, you might have created hash with debug key, and entered there, ........ just a random guess

Comment: @viv  yes. i generated a hash key by keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey.... command...is it the wrong way to generate the key? if it is?....then what will be the right way to generate a hash key?

Comment: You used the debug key, which is used when you directly run the app from eclipse, but if you export with your keystore then you have to create hash using that key, and enter at fb page

Comment: You can enter two hash keys at your fb page also, just as you created hash with debug key, create it with the key used at exporting